# Segmentation fault with echoping

Tags: linux, arch-linux, segmentation-fault

I'm testing smokeping's DNS probes with the echoping program as per the [documentation](https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/probe/EchoPingDNS.en.html), but for me this is causing a segmentation fault when the command is executed by smokeping. I grabbed the command that smokeping is trying to run from `systemctl status smokeping.service` and tried to run it myself as my normal user and root:

`echoping -w 1 -p 6 -t 1 -6 -m /usr/lib/echoping/dns.so -n 20 facebook.com -t AAAA --tcp facebook.com`

It exits due to a: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

`strace` output is [here](https://pastebin.com/NDki2dU0).

The distribution of my test box is Arch Linux 4.20 kernel. I've tested this on LTS kernel 4.19 too which is also unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Actual command smokeping is trying to run:

`echoping -w 1 -P 0xa0 -p 6 -t 1 -6 -m /usr/lib/echoping/dns.so -n 20 facebook.com -t AAAA --tcp facebook.com`

(I missed the `-P 0xa0` because I tried omitting the flag before posting but should have copied the command prior to the most recent that I ran...)

UPDATE:

backtrace from the core dump:

```
$ gdb /usr/bin/echoping core.27236 
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2.1
...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/echoping...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 27236]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `echoping -w 1 -P 0xa0 -p 6 -t 1 -6 -m /usr/lib/echoping/dns.so -n 20 facebook.c'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f73c938246a in init () from /usr/lib/echoping/dns.so

(gdb) backtrace full
#0  0x00007f73c938246a in init () from /usr/lib/echoping/dns.so
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000564855557d58 in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Comment: What does the backtrace in the coredump say? It's unlikely that the SEGV is from a system call.

Comment: @ChrisDown as it happens I'm not seeing a core dump in the cwd. Is the dump placed elsewhere?

Comment: @ChrisDown just reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-the-current-directory so I'll update when I figure out where the core dump goes.

Comment: @ChrisDown I've updated the question with the backtrace.

Answer (score 2):

That's simply a bug in `echoping(1)`, and you should go report it (after checking if they hadn't already fixed it in the last version).

---

In the `util.c` file from its source code, they have this little c-x-er:

```
char           *
to_upper(char *input)
{
        int             c;
        char           *result;
        result = (char *) malloc(strlen(input));
        for (c = 0; c < strlen(input); c++)
                result[c] = toupper((int)input[c]);
        result[strlen(input)] = '\0';
        return result;
}
```

Notice how `result[strlen(input)]` will write 1 byte beyond the length of the buffer allocated with `malloc()`.

But that's not all; instead of declaring the correct prototype of `to_upper()` (which returns a 64 bit pointer on x86-64), they let the compiler assume that it returns a 32 bit int and **force cast** its return value to `(char*)` in `plugins/dns/dns.c`:

```
char           *
init(const int argc, const char **argv)
{
   ...
                upper_type_name = (char *) to_upper(type_name);
```

This latter really kills it, and I don't think that has *ever* run on x86-64; your only hope is to configure your system as multiarch and install `echoping` as a 32bit binary; example (not tested) for debian:

```
apt-get remove echoping
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install echoping:i386
```

[I've used the sources of echoping-6.0.2, that I've got with `apt-get source echoping` in debian 9.]

Comment: I wouldn't know how to contact the developer as echoping isn't on GitHub and I can't find it at Sourceforge. This is a terrific answer though.

Comment: It looks like it's [not developed anymore](https://github.com/bortzmeyer/echoping/). The multiarch + i386 binary approach seems to work, but that command will die with "IPv6 name servers not supported on this platform, may be you should use the -4 option".